# Reading ICC_IAR1_EL1 register causes several exceptions?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I'm working on a bare-metal interrupt controller. The underlying architecture is Virt, with QEMU, and a CPU Arm Cortex-72, aarch64. As an example, I provide you an excerpt of the Makefile:

```
run:
    $(MAKE) kernel.elf
    qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -cpu cortex-a72 -nographic -kernel kernel.elf
```

I defined an exception handler that is called everytime an exception occurs. This is an excerpt (output is written on a UART):

```
void common_trap_handler(exception_frame *exc)
{ 
    uart_puts("\nException Handler! (");
    uint32_t val = raw_read_current_el();
    uart_puts("\n\tCurrent EL = ");
    uart_puthex(val);
    uart_puts("\t");

    uart_puts("exc_type : ");
    uart_puthex(exc->exc_type);
    
    val = raw_read_icc_iar1_el1();
    uart_puts("\n\tICC IAR1 EL1 = ");
    uart_puthex(val); 
    // rest of the exception handler
}
```

Accesses to registers are done through assembly code. Reading the current exception level works:

```
uint32_t raw_read_current_el(void)
{
    uint32_t current_el;
    __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %0, CurrentEL\n\t" : "=r" (current_el) :  : "memory");
    return current_el;
}
```

Reading `ICC_IAR1_EL1` register does not (more details below):

```
uint32_t raw_read_icc_iar1_el1(void)
{
    uint32_t icc_iar1_el1 = 0;
    __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %0, s3_0_c12_c12_0\n\t" : "=r" (icc_iar1_el1) :  : "memory");
    return icc_iar1_el1; 
}
```

Where `s3_0_c12_c12_0` is the ID of `ICC_IAR1_EL1` according to arm specifications, since it is defined as a "register without an architectural name".

Getting access to `ICC_IAR1_EL1` triggers a limitless number of other exceptions. This is an excerpt of the output (repeated several times):

```
Exception Handler! (
    Current EL = 0x00000000 00000004    exc_type : 0x00000000 00000011
Exception Handler! (
    Current EL = 0x00000000 00000004    exc_type : 0x00000000 00000011
Exception Handler! (
    Current EL = 0x00000000 00000004    exc_type : 0x00000000 00000011
```

I can't understand why. According to the name of the register `ICC_IAR1_EL1`, this register should be accessed with a minimum privilege of EL1. This is verified by the output `Current EL = 0x00000000 00000004`. Do you know how can I read the content of `ICC_IAR1_EL1` register? Unfortunately, [the official ARM guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2020-12/AArch64-Registers/) did not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you want your qemu-virt machine to use a GICv3 in order to be able to use the register interface to the GIC, and not a GICv2 with a memory-mapped interface, which is the version of the GIC used by default by the qem-virt machine.

The following command is working fine:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -cpu cortex-a72 -nographic -kernel kernel.elf
```

My test program:

```
                .title minimal-aarch64.s
                .arch armv8-a
                .text
                .section .text.startup,"ax"    
                .globl _start
                .weak test
_start:
                ldr x0, =__StackTop
                mov sp, x0
                bl  test
wait:           wfe
                b wait

test:           
                mrs x0, s3_0_c12_c12_0
                ret
               .end
```

Using your command or

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=2 -cpu cortex-a72 -nographic -kernel kernel.elf
```

Does result in an exception being raised before the program returning from the `test` subroutine, which is the behaviour you observed:

```
Breakpoint 2, test () at minimal-aarch64.s:15
0x0000000000000200 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Dear Frant, I got the problem, thanks. I think there is a little issue in your answer: ,gic-version=3 did not work, gic_version=3 (with the underscore) has worked.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting feedback. I am using a vanilla qemu 5.2.0 I compiled from sources with the exact commands I provided. Using `-machine virt,gic_version=3 ` gives the following error message on my system: `Property 'virt-5.2-machine.gic_version' not found`. You may be using a different version, which may explain the discrepancies. The [documentation](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/arm/virt.html) is using `'-'`'as well.

Comment: The flavor of `gic-version` using an underscore instead of a caret was being referenced in a 2016 article on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM64/QEMU). This was probably an accepted syntax until recently. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Dear Frant, by placing gic_version=3 I can access to ICC_IAR1_EL1, but I am literally invaded by exceptions whose INTID is 1023. Basically, as far as I know, 1023 is a spurious interrupt, namely there are no enabled INTIDs in the pending state, or all INTIDs in that pending are of insufficient priority to be taken. I can't understand why I using this option gic_version=3 leads to receive lots of spurious interrupts. Did you face a similar problem?

Comment: What are you doing besides reading `ICC_IAR1_EL1` ? I would need the exact sequence of operations you are using. Would you envisage opening a new question, and providing the minimal test program I used augmented by the exact sequence of operations your are using? I would definitively be willing to investigate your issue, and so may others.

Comment: Dear Frant, I come back to you with a question related to your answer. You told me "You need to specify that you want your qemu-virt machine to use a GICv3 in order to be able to use the register interface to the GIC, and not a GICv2 with a memory-mapped interface, which is the version of the GIC used by default by the qem-virt machine.". But, why can I read "CurrentEL" register without problems? Theorectically, it should raise the same issue of ICC_IAR1_EL1, non? Thanks

Comment: Hi Joe, I don't think so,  because `CurrentEL` is not related to the `GIC` sub-system, and is always present on an `armv8-a` processor. My understanding is that GIC-related registers are present in a processor only if it is implementing a `GICv3` (or a `GICv4`). This is not always the case: you can  know if the GIC register interface is available by reading `ID_AA64PFR0_EL1` - see section `D12.2.56 ID_AA64PFR0_EL1, AArch64 Processor Feature Register 0` of the `ARM® Architecture Reference Manual ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile`.

Comment: `mrs x0, ID_AA64PFR0_EL1` sets `x0` to `0x00002222` with `-machine virt,gic-version=2`, and to `0x01002222` with `-machine virt,gic-version=3`. As per the documentation: 
GIC, [27:24]
   GIC CPU interface:
    0x0 GIC CPU interface is disabled, GICCDISABLE is HIGH, or not implemented.
    0x1 GIC CPU interface is implemented and enabled, GICCDISABLE is LOW.

Comment: See page 17 of [GICv3 and GICv4 Software Overview](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f1068720daa596235e7f6ef?token=): NOTE: Software can check for GIC System register support by reading ID_AA64PFR0_EL1for the PE, see ARM®Architecture Reference Manual, ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile for details.

Comment: Very very clear, thank you Frant! I think this discussion will be useful to others as well.